# Gtk# App on Mac -- calling mplayer as a process results in process window being shown

Tags: c#, macos, process, gtk#, mplayer

I have a gtk# media player app that is currently working on Windows! Yay!  I just got it running on the mac, it uses mplayer for playing of media as a separate process in slave mode.  The problem is that even though I am setting the ProcessStyle as hidden and setting createnowindow=true I can see the mplayer window and it switches the context from MY APP to mplayer.  This is a big problem because I don't want the user to have to keep clicking back to the app:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new             System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = mplayerFileUrl;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-slave -quiet " + file;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        mplayerProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
        mplayerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
mplayerProcess.Start();
        mplayerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```